# Is there a tool that puts on a webserver some .html or .php files filled with popular malware like java drive-bys or other browser exploit payloads?

Tags: webserver, malware, php, virus, java

As mentioned in the title I'm looking for a tool that puts on a webserver some .html or .php files filled with popular malware like java drive-bys or other browser exploit payloads? Maybe there is something like this in Metasploit or on BackTrack?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Social Engineer Toolkit ([SET](http://www.social-engineer.org/framework/Computer_Based_Social_Engineering_Tools%3a_Social_Engineer_Toolkit_%28SET%29)) has something like what you ask for.

It allows you to create websites with various attack vectors.

Check out the 'Tactical Nuke' option for a widespread test.

This is found on Backtrack and integrates with Metasploit.

Comment: that seems to be what I was looking for..thanks a lot!

Comment: do you know SET or metasploit payloads that work without user interaction?

Comment: without user interaction, then it wouldn't be 'social' :) Metasploit has many tools to hack a computer without interaction.

Comment: that's true somehow ;) could you name a few? i'm not very much into metasploit, just want to try it out myself on a VM.

Comment: you are looking for 'autopwn' on http://www.offensive-security.com/metasploit-unleashed/Main_Page